# Why should I write "she asked me to not phone" instead of the usual "she asked me not to phone"

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs

While studying for a grammar exam (I'm a foreigner speaker) one example said
"she asked me to not phone" instead of the usual order "she asked me not to phone".
The only thing that came to my mind is that being "ask to" a phrasal we can't avoid the "to" after the pronoun so we don't write a second "to" to avoid cacophony because in fact we should write "she asked me to not to phone".
Am I right? Can anyone elaborate?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Are split infinitives grammatically incorrect, or are they valid constructs?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs).

Comment: What was the context? Was the first version presented as correct? It's odd to be.

Comment: What are you saying about «a second “to”»?

Comment: The versions with a single *to* are fine; the last with "to not to" isn't. The word order *to not phone* produces a stronger request than the word order *not to phone*.